# The active Tests Run was aborted. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, abort

Facing the below issue while running a test method, but not always.Once i face this issue, I cannot run any other test method further.

```
The active Tests Run was aborted.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.WriteByte(Byte value)
   at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(Byte value)
   at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write7BitEncodedInt(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.SocketCommunicationManager.WriteAndFlushToChannel(String rawMessage)
   at M

    icrosoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.SocketCommunicationManager.SendMessage(String messageType)
       at Microsoft.TestPlatform.VsTestConsole.TranslationLayer.VsTestConsoleRequestSender.AbortTestRun()
       at Microsoft.TestPlatform.VsTestConsole.TranslationLayer.VsTestConsoleWrapper.AbortTestRun() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.TestPlatformV2.ProxyRunRequest.Abort()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.TestPlatformV2.ProxyRunRequest.Dispose()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<RunRequests>d__95.MoveNext()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<ProcessRequest>d__94.MoveNext()
     ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:00.0408906) ==========



    

Can i get any solution for this error other than upgrading to latest version of VS 2019. Currently I am using VS 2019 version 16.2.
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with Visual Studio version. Could it be a network issue?

Comment: How often do you see the error? You may also give `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` a try

Comment: See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/496822/unit-testing-issue-the-active-tests-run-was-aborte.html. It sounds like you may need to upgrade your Visual Studio